# How to extract specific from an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

How can I remove an property from an array? I wish to remove the property that includes:

```
someObject = { number: '1', month: 'march', year: '2023' }
```

And I have an array:

```
someArray = ['month', 'year'] or a string 'month, year'
```

And want to extract so that I get:

```
finalObject = {  month: 'march', year: '2023' }
```

Comment: is the needs of your problem includes the nested properties ?

Comment: Hello, no it will not include nested properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write a function that maps your keys into `[key, value]` subarrays, using the initial object to extract the values, then use `Object.fromEntries` to combine these into a new object:

```js
const extract = (object, keys) =>
  Object.fromEntries(keys.map(key => [key, object[key]]))

const someObject = { number: '1', month: 'march', year: '2023' } 
const someArray = ['month', 'year']

console.log(extract(someObject, someArray))
```

### Update

A comment asked to include only those keys whose values actually appear in the original object.  This is only a minor tweak:

```js
const extract = (object, keys) =>
  Object.fromEntries(keys.flatMap(key => key in object ? [[key, object[key]]] : []
))
```

Comment: IDK who downvotes this, Your approach based on functional programming is better, just a little note about if there's a key in `someArray` that does not exist as a property in an `someObject`,  I think in that case should not be included as part of finalObject!

Comment: @XMehdi01: added an updated version to deal with that possibility.

Comment: Thanks, I went with this approach because it only loops one time as you said it would. Either way all the answers works as well. I gave useful votes

Answer (score 2):

loop over `keys and values` with `Object.entries` with the help of `filter` to let only keys that exist in `propertiesToExtract` and turn them back into object with `Object.fromEntries`

```js
const someObject = { number: '1', month: 'march', year: '2023' } 
const propertiesToExtract = ['month', 'year']; //if it is string 'month, year' turn it into array with the help of .split(', ');
const finalObject = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(someObject).filter(([key,value])=>propertiesToExtract.includes(key)));
console.log(finalObject); // {  month: 'march', year: '2023' }
```

Comment: See my answer for a similar approach, but which loops only over the properties we care to include rather than filtering over all of them.

Answer (score 1):

To remove an object from an array based on specific properties, you can use the filter() method along with the includes() method. Here's how you can achieve the desired result:

```
const someObject = { number: '1', month: 'march', year: '2023' };
const someArray = ['month', 'year']; // or const someArray = 'month, year';

// Convert the someArray string to an array if needed
const propertiesToRemove = Array.isArray(someArray) ? someArray : someArray.split(', ');

// Filter the properties of someObject based on propertiesToRemove
const finalObject = Object.keys(someObject)
  .filter(key => propertiesToRemove.includes(key))
  .reduce((obj, key) => {
    obj[key] = someObject[key];
    return obj;
  }, {});

console.log(finalObject);
```

In this code, we first define the someObject and someArray variables as provided. Then, we convert the someArray string to an array if it is in string format.

Next, we use Object.keys() to get an array of keys from someObject. We filter this array based on whether the properties in propertiesToRemove are present using the includes() method. Then, using reduce(), we create a new object finalObject by iterating over the filtered keys and assigning the corresponding values from someObject to the finalObject.

Finally, we log the finalObject to the console, which will contain only the properties specified in someArray or someArray string.

Note: The code assumes that the properties to remove exist in someObject. If there's a possibility that some properties might not exist in someObject, you can add additional checks to handle such cases.

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow.  It looks like it's been a while since you've posted and may not be aware of the current policies since you posted 7 answers today, most or all of which appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.